# Why does my class variable in my Application Delegate not get instantiated?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, delegates, initialization

This issue has been bugging me for a while now and somehow I cannot find what I'm doing wrong. I must say I am new to Objective-C and Xcode.

So the issue is that I try to declare an instance variable (NSMutableArray) but for some reason the init function is NEVER reached. The variable is always NULL.

So I have a class named PropertyProvider which contains a NSMutableArray named "properties".

```
@interface PropertyProvider : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *properties;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *properties;

..

@end
```

I then instantiate this NSMutableArray in the init method of this PropertyProvider class as the following:

```
@implementation PropertyProvider

@synthesize properties;

- (id) init {
    self = [super init];

    NSLog(@"Instantiating PropertyProvider");

    if (self) {
        properties = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

.. more code ..

@end
```

In my Application delegate I try to instantiate the PropertyProvider as "prp":

```
@implementation MyAppDelegate

@synthesize prp = _prp;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [[_prp init] alloc];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

.. more code ..

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_prp release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

But thus, for some reason it never reaches the **init** method of my **PropertyProvider**. Why o why?!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of initializing `_prp` as an instance of `PropertyProvider` would be,

```
_prp = [[PropertyProvider alloc] init];
```

Since `_prp` is an instance variable, it is `nil` by default and hence messages to it don't do anything which is the reason why you're not getting any errors.

Comment: Shit, you are so right. Stupid from me not to see it.. Sigh.. Must have been staring at it for too long! Thanks a lot!
And sorry for the stupid question.. : )

Comment: @Jules: it is not a stupid question if it helped you fix your problem.